# About Float left and right

Tags: html, css, css-float

Hello I am a new web developer. I have a simple problem. 
I am trying two column site in a div  (.container width960px) one is float: left(width:300px) but when another using float: right(width:650px ) . But when I  am using float right rightsidebar did not appear in container. Pleasr help me proper use on float: left or right.

```
.container {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}

.leftsidebar {
    width: 200px;
    float:left
}

.rightsidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a snippet or example of the problem? We can't know what's wrong if we can't see anything.

Comment: You can use jsfiddle or http://plnkr.co/ to show your problem..

You said did not appear. Do you mean it appears but not side-by-side?

Comment: I am using .container{background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;}  and .leftsidebar{width: 200px;float:left} 
.rightsidebar{float: left;
width: 200px;
color: #fff;
width: 400px;} right sidebar did not appear right. It appear on bottom with background color no container color.

Comment: Can you provide some your code for this to allow us to help you?

Comment: we really need a code sample to figure out why your code isn't working. It's a fairly easy thing to setup so I made a jsbin with working code, I even went ahead and made it fluid : http://jsbin.com/jedoferayuno/1/ (play with the numbers and see how it works). I originally had it set to the exact numbers you mentioned, but what I'm showing is what I think is a better way to handle this type of layout.

Answer (score 0):

The result you want, is simple. There shouldn't be any problem, check this sample based on yours:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftsidebar">
        Right Sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="rightsidebar">
        Right Sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}

.leftsidebar {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background: yellow;
}

.rightsidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 760px;
    background: green;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9f06bwga/).